# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ QMediaPlayer - unable to play sound

Tags: audio, qt

I'm struggling to play audio files using Qt 5.11.3 and the QMediaPayer class.
There is no sound output when playing either .mp3 or .wav files.
I had some success to play a wav file using QSound class.

I have also set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS to 1 but I can't see any clear error.

My goal is to be able to play .mp3 files using the Qt implementation.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? if yes, can you please share your solution with us. I got the same issue and don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sound dumb, but the only thing missing was `gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio`.
I missed to notice that one of the components needed pulseaudio, so I think that the pulseaudio install broke my Qt.